# Lines in Logplot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to add vertical lines as markers in a LogPlot. When I am doing this in a normal Plot works fine. When I change to LogPlot the lines start from a value of y=1 and not from 0,01 as I have defined them. Does someone know how can I fix it?

```
line1 = Line[{{10*10^9, 0.01}, {10*10^9, 2}}];
line2 = Line[{{30*10^9, 0.01}, {30*10^9, 2}}];
line3 = Line[{{200*10^9, 0.01}, {200*10^9, 2}}];
lineStyle = {Black, Dashed};

Plot[dw //. {h -> 2, vs -> 200, H -> 5}, {EE, 1*10^9, 300*10^9}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.01}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {{Blue}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
 Epilog -> {Directive[lineStyle], line1, line2, line3}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{#, 10^-9 #} & /@ 
     FindDivisions[{1*10^9, 300*10^9, 10}, 10] // N, Automatic}]
```

[image]

```
LogPlot[dw //. {h -> 2, vs -> 200, H -> 5}, {EE, 1*10^9, 300*10^9}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.01}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {{Blue}}, 
     BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[lineStyle], line1, line2, line3}, 
     FrameTicks -> {{#, 10^-9 #} & /@ 
         FindDivisions[{1*10^9, 300*10^9, 10}, 10] // N, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include data for `dw`?

Comment: Why not use `GridLines` instead to mark the verticals?

Answer (score 2):

You need to scale the y-coordinate of the `Line` objects via `Log`.  Notice that the lines start near `y=1`, this is because `E^0.01=1.01`.

You can modify your original lines by a replacement rule,

```
LogPlot[dw //. {h -> 2, vs -> 200, H -> 5}, {EE, 1*10^9, 300*10^9},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.01}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True},
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {{Blue}},
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
 Epilog -> {Directive[lineStyle], {line1, line2, line3} /. 
    Line[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] :> Line[{{a, Log@b}, {c, Log@d}}]},
 FrameTicks -> {{#, 10^-9 #} & /@ 
     FindDivisions[{1*10^9, 300*10^9, 10}, 10] // N, Automatic},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 300 10^9}, {0, 800}}]
```

[image]

or by using `MapAt`,

```
LogPlot[dw //. {h -> 2, vs -> 200, H -> 5}, {EE, 1*10^9, 300*10^9},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.01}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True},
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {{Blue}},
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
 Epilog -> {Directive[lineStyle], 
   MapAt[Log, {line1, line2, line3}, {All, 1, All, 2}]},
 FrameTicks -> {{#, 10^-9 #} & /@ 
     FindDivisions[{1*10^9, 300*10^9, 10}, 10] // N, Automatic},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 300 10^9}, {0, 800}}]
```

which gives the same result as above.