# Rectangle fillings obscures the plot

Tags: plotting, filling

I used two dashed lines in the following codes to separate my plot into three blocks filled with color. But the fillings would obscure the curves (`EtaH[n]` and `EpsilonH[n]`).

```
fill1 = Rectangle[{zerosofeta[[1]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[2]],
     Log@4}];
fill2 = Rectangle[{0, Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[1]], Log@4}];
fill3 = Rectangle[{zerosofeta[[2]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {70, Log@4}];

LogPlot[{\[Epsilon]H[n],Abs[\[Eta]H[n]]}, {n, 0, 70},PlotRange -> {10^(-11), 4}, 
 Epilog -> {{Directive[Black, 
      Dashed], 
     Line[{{zerosofeta[[1]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[1]], 
        Log@4}}]}, {Directive[Black, Dashed], 
     Line[{{zerosofeta[[2]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[2]], 
        Log@4}}]},{LightGreen, fill1}, {LightBlue, fill2}, {LightBlue, fill3}}]
```

where `zerosofeta` is a two-element list used to put the roots of `EtaH[n]`.

[image]

I have tried another way

```
curve = LogPlot[{\[Epsilon]H[n],Abs[\[Eta]H[n]]}, {n, 0, 70}, 
   PlotRange -> {10^(-11), 4}];
rectangles = 
  Graphics[{{LightGreen, fill1}, {LightBlue, fill2}, {LightBlue, 
     fill3},{Directive[Black, 
      Dashed], 
     Line[{{zerosofeta[[1]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[1]], 
        Log@4}}]}, {Directive[Black, Dashed], 
     Line[{{zerosofeta[[2]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[2]], 
        Log@4}}]}}];
Show[rectangles, curve]
```

but the axes disappear.

Do you have any idea?

updated: The functions `etaH[n]` and `epsilonH[n]` are composed of `InterploatingFunction` which is the numerical solution of a PDE. But I might have a generic one to replace `etaH[n]` for error finding

```
eta[n_] := Module[{e0 = 0.02, ni0 = 0.0, no0 = 33.2, s0 = 1.,
e1 = -6.3, ni1 = 33.2, no1 = 35.7, s1 = 0.5,
e2 = 0.3, ni2 = 35.7, no2 = 55, s2 = 1., ef = 3, nif = 55, nof = 65, sf = 2},
(e0/2) * (Tanh[(n - ni0)/s0] - Tanh[(n - no0)/s0]) +
(e1/2) * (Tanh[(n - ni1)/s1] - Tanh[(n - no1)/s1]) +
(e2/2) * (Tanh[(n - ni2)/s2] - Tanh[(n - no2)/s2]) +
(ef/2) * (Tanh[(n - nif)/sf] - Tanh[(n - nof)/sf])]
```

[image]

Comment: These are also undefined `{εH[n], Abs[ηH[n]]}`

Comment: yep, the definitions are not shown here for briefness

Comment: In principle it is expected that you present code that can run. if the definitions are that lengthy, you can cook up some toy model functions.

Comment: Hi there!
Ideally you want to post a code that replicates as closely as possible the output that you describe. This makes error-finding easier on the community. Could you replace your functions and variables with 'generic' ones so that it could run on any machine?

Comment: Sure! Thank you for your reminder. First time asking a question here 

Comment: Of course. No worries. We're here to help :)
It is a good question after all! I'll upvote it once you finish updating your post ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Epilog` is something that will bring the argument at the front of the `LogPlot` layer.
If you put your rectangles in the `Epilog` then they will mask your functions.

You can instead use `Prolog` to have them in the background.
This avoids the need to use multiple plots in the solution given by @bmf (although you should keep that method in mind as it is a very good one as well)

```
zerosofeta = {30, 
   38}; (*i have chosen the points to match yours roughly*)

fill1 = Rectangle[{zerosofeta[[1]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[2]],
     Log@4}];
fill2 = Rectangle[{0, Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[1]], Log@4}];
fill3 = Rectangle[{zerosofeta[[2]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {70, Log@4}];

LogPlot[{Sin[n]^2, 0.01 Sqrt[Tanh[n]]}, {n, 0, 70}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotRange -> {1. 10^-12, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"func_1", "func_2"},
 
 (*create the prolog background*)

 Prolog -> {{LightGreen, fill1}, {LightBlue, fill2}, {LightBlue, 
    fill3}},
 
 (*now add your epilog with the lines-you could instead use Gridlines*)

 Epilog -> {{Black, Dashed, 
    Line[{{zerosofeta[[1]], Log[1. 10^-12]}, {zerosofeta[[1]], 
       Log[4]}}]},
   {Black, Dashed, 
    Line[{{zerosofeta[[2]], Log[1. 10^-12]}, {zerosofeta[[2]], 
       Log[4]}}]},
   Inset["Phase I", {15, Log[10^-7]}],
   Inset["Phase II", {33.8, Log[10^-7]}],
   Inset["Phase III", {55, Log[10^-7]}]
   }]
```

[image]

Note that you could have also used `Gridlines` instead of `Lines` and an `Epilog`.

Lines are generally not the best to use with LogPlot as there is a small (but a bit annoying ;) ) scaling that you need to perform. [You can find this SE link useful.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108707/lines-in-logplot)

Comment: (+1) very nice use and explanation of `Prolog` vs `Epilog` and their scope

Comment: thanks!  :)
Admittedly, stacking plots is my go-to method for more complex plots, but here this felt simpler. Epilog is just a great little thing, but sometimes its sibling is just as great.

Comment: Thank you too! Also works well

Comment: Happy to hear it does. take care.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the problem correctly you want something like this:

> [image: overlay]

So, essentially you want to use [**`Overlay`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html?v=13.2).

The code:

```
zerosofeta = {-2, 10};
f[n_] := Log[1/Sqrt[n - 1]]^3
g[n_] := 1/Log[n + 2]^2
fill1 = Rectangle[{zerosofeta[[1]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[2]],
     Log@4}];
fill2 = Rectangle[{0, Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[1]], Log@4}];
fill3 = Rectangle[{zerosofeta[[2]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {70, Log@4}];
p1 = LogPlot[{f[n], Abs[g[n]]}, {n, 0, 70}, 
   PlotRange -> {10^(-11), 4}, 
   Epilog -> {{Directive[Black, Dashed], 
      Line[{{zerosofeta[[1]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[1]], 
         Log@4}}]}, {Directive[Black, Dashed], 
      Line[{{zerosofeta[[2]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[2]], 
         Log@4}}]}}];
p2 = LogPlot[{f[n], Abs[g[n]]}, {n, 0, 70}, 
   PlotRange -> {10^(-11), 4}, 
   Epilog -> {{Directive[Black, Dashed], 
      Line[{{zerosofeta[[1]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[1]], 
         Log@4}}]}, {Directive[Black, Dashed], 
      Line[{{zerosofeta[[2]], Log@(10^(-12))}, {zerosofeta[[2]], 
         Log@4}}]}, {LightGreen, fill1}, {LightBlue, 
      fill2}, {LightBlue, fill3}}];
Overlay[{p2, p1}]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works

Comment: @holywhat glad I was able to help :-)